# Is there a way to send coins to a contract without executing it?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

Is there a way in Ethereum to send coins to a smart contract without actually executing a smart contract? And also, as an extension to that question, is it possible to determine from Solidity that sending coins to a particular address will result in an external contract execution (ie, will it incur more gas than if you were simply sending the coins to a wallet address?).

Answer (score 1):

`selfdestruct(contractAddress)` should do the trick.  As a contract:

```
contract ForceSend {
  function ForceSend(address recipient) payable {
    selfdestruct(recipient);
  }
}
```

Deploy, send along the contract address as `recipient` and any Ether you want to send to the contract.

If you'd prefer something a little more permanent, consider a factory-based approach.  In addition to the above:

```
contract ForceSender {
  function forceSend(address recipient) payable {
    require(msg.value != 0);
    ForceSend f = (new ForceSend).value(msg.value)(recipient);
    assert(address(f) != address(0));
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not actually 100% sure the factory here will work as intended. I'm not sure what `address(f)` returns when `f` has called `selfdestruct`.  I think it will still return a non-0, but if it doesn't, it's hard to differentiate between a failed contract creation and a successful one.

Comment: heh that's actually pretty interesting. But is there a way to send a particular amount (rather than all coins belonging to a contract) and without destroying the contract?

Comment: Then you send the particular amount to `ForceSend` on deployment. This contract is used to send Ether as per your request. That is the purpose of `ForceSend`.

Comment: Added a factory pattern to go along with it, to make it slightly more reusable.  You can adapt the factory pattern to send values other than `msg.value`, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Sending ether to a contract does not execute it.

Contract's `constructor` gets called only once, when the contract is mined.
After that you need to be calling a particular function. Without specifying a particular function, the invocation defaults to the `default function`. Every smart contract has a `default function` that does nothing and is **not** payable.

Look at implementing a fallback function; From solidity docs:

> **What is the deal with function () { ... } inside Solidity contracts? How can a function not have a name?**
>
> This function is called “fallback function” and it is called when someone just sent Ether to the contract without providing any data or
>   if someone messed up the types so that they tried to call a function
>   that does not exist.
>
> **The default behaviour (if no fallback function is explicitly given) in these situations is to throw an exception**.
>
> If the contract is meant to receive Ether with simple transfers, you should implement the fallback function as:
>
> ```
> function() payable { }
> ```
>
> Another use of the fallback function is to e.g. register that your contract received ether by using an event.
>
> **Attention: If you implement the fallback function take care that it uses as little gas as possible, because send() will only supply a
>   limited amount.**